# Rails find by ids where column is true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to select by a group of ids but only if the `shown` column is true. I tried:
`Product.find(@product_ids, conditions: "shown = true")`

However that gives me the error: `Couldn't find all Products with IDs (2, 3) [WHERE (shown = true)] (found 0 results, but was looking for 2)`

In this particular case, both of the products selected have `shown` set to false.

Comment: From the guides: "Model.find(array_of_primary_key) will raise an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception unless a matching record is found for all of the supplied primary keys.". That's why you're receiving this exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `where`.

```
Product.where("id in (?) and shown = ?", @product_ids, true)
```

or

```
Product.where(id: @product_ids, shown: true)
```

or

```
Product.where("id in (:product_ids) and shown = :shown", { product_ids: @product_ids, shown: true })
```